# Gazetteer Loading in gate

Tags: gate

I am using gate 7.1.  in that i have 30 .def files are loading every time.

I have run multiple text files every time all 30 .def files loading if any possibility to load all 30 .def files into single object and send that object to gazetteer.

add multiple def files at a time to anniecontroller

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i am asking how to add multiple .def files to annie controller

Comment: The answer is: Add multiple gazetteer processing resources to the controller (one gazetteer per .def file).

Comment: i am not understand please explain clearly

Comment: present i am using ofaiList gazetteer it takes more time to load lst files now i am change ofai to extended gazetteer but some features are not available in extended gazetteer how to enable those features based on ofai list gazetteer.

Answer (score 1):

Vijay,

I do not believe it is possible to load def files within a single def file.

The **Definition** (or Index) file specifically references a list (lst) file. **List** files reference terms, majorType, minorType, language, and the list display name.
For example:

*testList:majorType=Major Type:minorType=Minor Type*

The resulting .def would look like:

*testList.lst:Major Type:Minor Type:English: Test List*

The definition file can only contain list file references. That being said, You can alter the structure of the definition file to meet your needs. There are several different way to do this, all permutations of the same concept.

1. Add all lists under one def file with each list having a different label,
2. Build a small set of def files with related lists,
3. Build a larger set of def files that evolve from other lists.

Question is, what are you trying to do?

Comment: Please don't ask a question in your answer. If you need to ask a question, then ask it in the comments.

Comment: in my application i am using 30 .def files. 30 .def files having a  different .lst files i merge all the .lst files into single .def gazetteer not loading that much of memory its getting out of memory. i trying to loading all def files into one object pass that object to gazetteer.

Comment: How to put at a time multiple .def files to FeatureMap 'FeatureMap gparams = Factory.newFeatureMap();'   not using for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , It is possible to load multiple def files . You can do it by using `annie plugin` .So , First you have to load that plugin from `CREOLE` option.Select `ANNIE` from it .
After that, you can select `Annie Gazetteer` as a processing resource. Then their, you can add multiple def files paths, where you just need to give the paths of `def` files.